# Route specific IP through OpenVPN

Tags: network, vpn

I have an `.ovpn` configuration file which allows me to reach endpoints on the VPN if I uncomment `redirect-gateway def1`, but I do not want all network traffic going through the VPN. Only certain endpoints.

If I try and visit an internal website, let's say `42.123.123.10` with `redirect-gateway def1` present it works. If I comment `redirect-gateway def1` and use any of the following it does not work.

Additionally, I cannot see the interface named `ovpn-tun` when running `ifconfig` so I am not sure what to set network rules on if I configured a script to add routes or what have you.

Attempted

```
route-nopull
route 42.123.123.10 255.255.255.255 ;OR the following line
route 42.123.123.10 255.255.255.0   ;OR the following line
route 42.123.123.10
```

Base Config

```
route-nopull
client
dev ovpn-tun
remote {REDACTED} 1194 udp
cipher AES-256-CBC
auth SHA512
resolv-retry infinite
;redirect-gateway def1
route 42.123.123.10
nobind
persist-key
persist-tun
user nobody
group nogroup
verb 10
```

Answer (score 1):

I forgot the interface must be an existing one, so I used `utun` which is on macOS by default.

I removed all entries for `route` in the OpenVPN config file and instead installed `iproute2mac` via homebrew, `brew install iproute2mac` so I have access to the `ip` command which I am used to the syntax of.

I then ran `ip route add 42.123.123.10 dev utun2` (I know my interface will be utun2 as without OpenVPN running there are two `utun` interfaces for me, `utun0`, and `utun1` checked with `ifconfig` or `ip r`.

Now it works.

OpenVPN allows you to run scripts via the configuration files so I will dump these route add and route delete rules in some files.